# Do I need to run a pallet storage migrations even when I'm just adding the pallet to the runtime for the first time?

Tags: try-runtime, storage-migration

Do I need to run a pallet storage migrations even when I'm just adding the pallet to the runtime for the first time?

This question came up because while testing the upgrade using the try-runtime cli, for pallets that where recently added but the storage version is greater than zero I get the following error `On chain storage version StorageVersion(0) doesn't match current storage version StorageVersion(4).`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies depending on the pallet. For certain pallets, you must configure the genesis data.

If there is no genesis data that needs to be set, you can disregard the migration and manually set the storage version.

Refer to https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blame/96d48b943b903e941132b7fbb69a7c40cfd4573a/runtime/crab/src/migration.rs#L47-L51 for more information.